# Will 4/4 rough sawn white oak warp over time?

Tags: lumber, warp, storage

I have a bunch of 9' long by 6" 4/4 rough sawn (flat sawn) white oak in my garage. I'm curious as to whether I should expect it to cup and/or bow over time. It's kiln dried. I have it in stacks, 11 pieces high, on some 2 x 2 yellow pine every 14 inches or so to keep it off the floor. I live in a relatively humid climate. Should I expect that this lumber will change much over time? I don't plan on using it for the better part of a year. Is there anything besides what I've mentioned that I should do to keep it more stable?

Comment: Wood that has been already been dried properly and is stickered as you have it should remain stable indoors. And it can remain as you have it for *years* and pretty much not be bothered. Since you say you have a bunch, are these multiple slices from the same tree by any chance? If so do you have the one that aligned with the centre and either of the two adjacent boards?

Comment: @Graphus thanks. I have 200 board feet, but I don't know if I have any quarter or rift sawn. Is that what you're asking about? I hope I do, but I think this distributor separates out all of the quarter sawn to sell elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I was checking if you knew about the centre board being QS and the two adjacent ones being essentially RS, and how you might want to selectively use this wood for its lower movement rate and/or the figure.

Comment: @Graphus Oh I see, thank you so much for looking out. I am hoping to find a couple quartersawn pieces with some nice ray fleck. I'm planning to use the old steel wool staining technique to darken the wood in a neutral way without changing the hue much. I think some QS boards could look really cool this way.

Comment: If your oak is relatively high in tannins an iron acetate solution (steel wool dissolved in vinegar) will turn it grey or even nearly black which I presume is not what you want? Tannin level is surprisingly varied in oak despite it being noted for its tannin content so it's impossible to know in advance what you're going to get, and variation in colour board to board should be expected. If I'm interpreting the colour change you want correctly I think you might want fuming instead, and Ben Strano of Fine Woodworking looked at this recently, comparing different strengths of ammonia & fume times.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks. I actually watched the video with Ben. That was great. I just was having a hard time trying to imagine how I could possibly fume such large quantities of wood. I was thinking of making a slightly diluted solution of this vinegar steel wool and experimenting with pieces of the wood first, but I hadn't really thought about how different one board might be compared to the next, but I can totally imagine my project turning out to be some kind of hodgepodge of various shades, that's a really good point. It'll be sometime before I even get there, but I really appreciate this advice.

Comment: *"having a hard time trying to imagine how I could possibly fume such large quantities"* Don't do it all, do your project pieces after they're completed (you may have to do it this way anyway, but also it is the norm for this technique) and if necessary in batches depending on the size of the fume tent you can organise. In fact it wasn't (isn't?) unusual for the complete furniture piece to be fumed, fully assembled, in case you didn't know.

Comment: *"a slightly diluted solution of this vinegar steel wool and experimenting with pieces of the wood first"* Well do that anyway, good to view the colours you'll get with your own eyes and also you need to try various finishes over the stained surface to see how much they deepen the colour and/or change the hue. FWIW the best brown tones I've seen created with vinegar were on beech. Very strong tea was used on the wood as well, to strengthen and even out the colour. This achieved a deep chocolate brown after finishing, which if memory serves was done by oiling followed by button polish.

Comment: @Graphus things are done for all of this advice. I especially did not know that it was a common practice to tent the entire finish piece for fuming. I'm going to experiment with fuming for sure now.

Comment: Welcome. We're gettin' way off topic here and Comments aren't for extended discussion but [here](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/woodworking-blogs/create-fumed-finish/) on PW is a good simple overview of how you might approach it (and showing how rudimentary a tent can be, which is good to know hehe). Also [this](https://woodandshop.com/how-to-fume-ammonia-fuming-experiment-cheap-ammonia/) on Wood and Shop demonstrates how you might more easily contain the fumes for smaller pieces, which as you'll see would be great for boxes and other smaller items (totally going to try this myself).

Comment: @Graphus Awesome, seeing that rudimentary Tent on PW gives me confidence! I could just use a plastic dropcloth. Thanks yet again!

Comment: @Graphus I ordered and received a bottle of 28% (aqueous) ammonia, I'm excited to give it a try, that stuff makes me nervous to have around, but I am excited to give it a try. I did try a small sample of the iron acetate solution as well, and I'm so glad I ordered the ammonia when you suggested it, because I agree 100% with you that the iron acetate is very difficult to get to a color that you want and with consistency. It kind of looks cheap, compared to typical fuming results.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm sure you'll be very pleased by what the ammonia does, it seems to always give quite decent results. Re. the iron acetate, yeah I think unless one is looking to produce a look similar to weathered wood (on pine and other low-tannin woods) where irregular results don't matter so much, or want to achieve a solid black it's not really of great use. And there are faster/easier ways of achieving a solid black!